# why my 'then' promise chaining keep executed even though I have sent the response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a code like to set up sign up process. this is in my controller in the node application, here is the complete code

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")

const User = require("../models/user") // mongoose model
const ResponseData = require("../models/structureResponse")

exports.signUp= (req,res,next) => {

    const email = req.body.email
    const plainPassword = req.body.password
    const saltRounds = 12

    User.findOne({email: email})
    .then((userData) => {

        if (userData) {
            const response = new ResponseData(1,"user already exist",{})
            res.status(409).json(response)
        } else {
            return bcrypt.hash(plainPassword, saltRounds)
        }

    })
    .then((hashedPassword) => {

        const user = new User({
            email: email,
            password: hashedPassword
        })

        return user.save()
    })
    .then((user) => {

        const response = new ResponseData(1,"Successfully create a user",user)
        res.status(409).json(response)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        const error = new Error(err);
        error.httpStatusCode = 500;
        return next(error);
    })



}
```

the first step is to check whether the user is already exist or not, checked by their email using `User.findOne` , if the user is exist, then this code is executed:

```
       if (userData) {
            const response = new ResponseData(1,"user already exist",{})
            res.status(409).json(response)
        }
```

when I send the response like that, and tell the client the user is already exist, the next 'then' is also executed. I mean this part:

```
.then((hashedPassword) => {

        const user = new User({
            email: email,
            password: hashedPassword
        })

        return user.save()
    })
```

I expect if I already send the response that tell "user already exist" , the 'then' below it will no longer executed. how to do that ? or do I write the wrong promise chaining ? to be honest I am new in node js

Answer (score 1):

You have to `return` your second `then()` too. Because right know you don't return your response.

```
.then((hashedPassword) => {

        const user = new User({
            email: email,
            password: hashedPassword
        })

        return user.save()
    })
    .then((user) => {

        const response = new ResponseData(1,"Successfully create a user",user)
       return res.status(409).json(response)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

`.then` callbacks returned value will be populated to the next `.then` callback parameter no matter if you return or not return anything from it.

There isn't a way to break a `.then` chain except for `throw` inside `.then` callback which will jump to the `catch` block.

You will have to break your function instead of chaining `.then`

I personally will use `async/await` like this

```
exports.signUp = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const email = req.body.email
    const plainPassword = req.body.password
    const saltRounds = 12

    const userExist = await User.findOne({ email })

    if (userExist) {
      const response = new ResponseData(1,"user already exist",{})
      res.status(409).json(response)
      // Now we are not inside a promise callback so we can
      // stop the execution of signUp by just returning from the function
      return
    }

    const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(plainPassword, saltRounds)

    const user = await new User({
      email: email,
      password: hashedPassword
    }).save()

    const response = new ResponseData(1,"Successfully create a user",user)
    res.status(409).json(response) 
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new Error(err)
    error.httpStatusCode = 500
    next(error)
  }
}
```

The equivalent with promises

```
exports.signUp = (req, res, next) => {
  const email = req.body.email
  const plainPassword = req.body.password
  const saltRounds = 12

  User.findOne({ email })
    .then((userData) => {
      if (userData) {
        const response = new ResponseData(1,"user already exist",{})
        res.status(409).json(response)
        // here we return but we dont have another .then function
        // so the rest of the code wont execute if userData is true
        return
      }

      const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hash(plainPassword, saltRounds)
      const user = new User({
        email: email,
        password: hashedPassword
      }).save()
        .then((user) => {
          const response = new ResponseData(1,"Successfully create a user",user)
          res.status(409).json(response)
        })
    }).catch((err) => {
      const error = new Error(err)
      error.httpStatusCode = 500
      next(error)
    })
}
```